# How to annotate Doctrine field with inheritance mapping?

Tags: inheritance, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have 2 entities.

```
/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="role", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"official" = "OfficialPerson"})
 *
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role")
     */
    private $role = 'user';


    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getRole()
    {
       return $this->role;
    }

}
```

And

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OfficialPerson extends Person
{

}
```

And I need to set getter and setter for this field, but it's duplicate definition of column 'role' on entity 'Person'. How to fix this and save getter and setter?

when i wrote

```
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="role", type="string")
```

and

```
* @ORM\Column(name="role")
```

Together in Person entity, I get an error

```
Duplicate definition of column 'role' on entity 'Person'
```

Comment: Do you want to call Person's `setRole` and `getRole` from OfficialPerson class ?

Comment: @AnjanaSilva need to have mapped property "role"  in field into database and have access to it from object

Comment: @fr051k actually `setRole` and `getRole` methods in Person class is already mapped. You can extend to those two function by declaring two new functions in OfficialPerson class. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @AnjanaSilva when i wrote  

    * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="role", type="string")

and

    * @ORM\Column(name="role")

I get an error 

    Duplicate definition of column 'role' on entity 'Person'

Comment: Apparently this is expected behavior for Doctrine and the only way around it is to create your own separate column, or to use `INSTANCEOF` for querying or `get_class` in your code. See http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-911

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have mapped in YAML files too. So it found two mappings, one from YAML and one from Annotations. Try removing Person.yml file under Resources/config/doctrine/.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!